# Generic type parser in scala 2.10

Tags: scala, generics

I'm writing a generic value parser using Scala 2.10. 
The input is a string and the output is a generic type, given by the user.

The only thing I can come up with is

```
val StringTYPE = classOf[java.lang.String]

def parseValue[T: ClassTag](str: String): T = {
  implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass match {
    case java.lang.Integer.TYPE => str.toInt.asInstanceOf[T]
    case java.lang.Long.TYPE => str.toLong.asInstanceOf[T]
    case StringTYPE => str.asInstanceOf[T]
    case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown type")
  }
}
```

But it seems very verbose and complicated, so I'm wondering is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems strange to use a run-time error for a compile-time condition. Did you consider a type class?

```
trait Readable[T] {
  def read(str: String): T
}

object Readable {


  implicit object IntIsReadable extends Readable[Int] {
    def read(str: String): Int = str.toInt
  }

  // ... provide similar objects for any types that can be "read" ...
  // if possible, inside object Readable 
  // or inside the companion object of the type you want to make readable. 
  // Otherwise, ensure that the implicit is in scope when calling Read
}


def readValue[T: Readable](str: String): T = implicitly[Readable[T]].read(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given by Aaron, the proper way to do that is the type class.

Just to suggest minor improvements to your version (but do not do that) you could check directly with the ClassTag. Also, naming the implicit parameter might be easier than getting it back with implicitly:

```
def parseValue[T](str: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): T = {
  if(tag == ClassTag.Int) str.toInt.asInstanceOf[T]
  else if(tag == ClassTag.Long) ...
  else if (tag == ClassTag(classOf[String]) …
  else ???
}
```